# Bracket syntax for custom struct types in Go

Tags: go

I'm willing to create C++ STL in Go. Is there a way to create custom structs that implement bracket syntax for index accessing?

Assume this is my array type:

```
type Array[T any] struct {
    values []T
}
```

Is there any way I can add bracket syntax indexation instead of `Array.At()` or any other?
I want to be able to access f.e index 4 using `Array[4]` instead of `Array.At(4)`.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As of the Go 1.19, Go does not support operator overloading (which is the general name for what you're asking for — `[]` being the specific operator you want to overload).

See [the FAQ](https://go.dev/doc/faq#overloading):

> Regarding operator overloading, it seems more a convenience than an absolute requirement. Again, things are simpler without it.

Comment: I assume `.At()` syntax to be the 'best' currently, right?

Comment: I don't know that there's a de-facto standard, but that method name would make sense to me, yeah.